Visual Basic, error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
Estoy realizando un Bingo. Al cargar el formulario se cargan 27 labels en forma de cartón de Bingo y cada casilla es un label(a), que va desde el label(0) al label (26). Lo que falla es la asignación de los números a las casillas. Por cada fila tienen que ir 5 números (1 en total) del 1 al 90, que no se repitan en todo el cartón y que en cada columna vayan números pertenecientes a su decena. O sea, la primera decena es del 1 al 10 (primera columna). Todo va bien hasta que me marca error dentro de un Case del Select Case, que dice:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
instance of an object.'

El error me lo marca en celda(Cel).Text = Rm.ToString(), pero supongo que en los otros 8 case también marcaría error. El código es el siguiente:
Public Class Form2
    Dim celda(28) As Label
    Dim Gen As New List(Of Integer) 'Gen es la lista donde se van "Gen-erando" números
    Dim Dec As New List(Of Integer) 'Dec es la lista donde se guarda la decena de los números salidos que son válidos
    Dim x, a, y, Cel, Rm, Ten As Integer

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        y = 200
        x = 0
        a = 0
        For P1 = 0 To 2
            For P2 = 0 To 8
                a = a + 1
                x = x + 55
                celda(a) = New Label
                celda(a).Name = "jugar" & a
                celda(a).Text = ""
                celda(a).Size = New Size(50, 50)
                celda(a).Tag = a
                celda(a).Location = New Point(x, y)
                celda(a).BackColor = Color.Green
                Controls.Add(celda(a))
            Next P2
            y = y + 55
            x = 0
        Next P1
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Randomize()
        a = 0 ''
        Cel = 0 'cel es una variable que ayuda a determinar el lugar de celda a tratar'

        For L1 As Integer = 0 To 2
            For L2 As Integer = 0 To 4
                While True 'Hasta que el número no pertenezca a alguna decena guardada'
                    Rm = Int((Rnd() * 90) + 1) 'Rn significa Número Random'
                    Ten = Int((Rm + 9) / 10) 'Ten significa Centena a la que Rm pertenece'
                    If Not Gen.Contains(Rm) AndAlso Not Dec.Contains(Ten) Then
                        Gen.Add(Rm)
                        Dec.Add(Ten)
                        Select Case a
                            Case Cel
                                If Ten = 1 Then
                                    celda(Cel).Text = Rm.ToString()
                                End If
                            Case Cel + 1
                                If Ten = 2 Then
                                    celda(Cel + 1).Text = Rm.ToString()
                                End If
                            Case cel + 2
                                If Ten = 3 Then
                                    celda(cel + 2).Text = Rm.ToString()
                                End If
                            Case Cel + 3
                                If Ten = 4 Then
                                    celda(Cel + 3).Text = Rm.ToString()
                                End If
                            Case Cel + 4
                                If Ten = 5 Then
                                    celda(Cel + 4).Text = Rm.ToString()
                                End If
                            Case Cel + 5
                                If Ten = 6 Then
                                    celda(Cel + 5).Text = Rm.ToString()
                                End If
                            Case Cel + 6
                                If Ten = 7 Then
                                    celda(Cel + 6).Text = Rm.ToString()
                                End If
                            Case Cel + 7
                                If Ten = 8 Then
                                    celda(Cel + 7).Text = Rm.ToString()
                                End If
                            Case Cel + 8
                                If Ten = 9 Then
                                    celda(Cel + 8).Text = Rm.ToString()
                                End If
                        End Select
                        Exit While
                    End If
                End While
            Next L2
            Cel = Cel + 9
            Dec.Clear()
        Next L1
    End Sub
End Class


Los Select Case son un problema. Me di cuenta que con el bucle While era más que suficiente. Una solución puede ser la siguiente:
Public Class Form2
    Dim celda(28) As Label
    Dim Gen As New List(Of Integer) 'Gen es la lista donde se van "Gen-erando" números
    Dim Dec As New List(Of Integer) 'Dec es la lista donde se guarda la decena de los números salidos que son válidos
    Dim x, a, y, Cel, Rm, Ten As Integer

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        y = 200
        x = 0
        a = 0
        For P1 = 0 To 2
            For P2 = 0 To 8
                a = a + 1
                x = x + 55
                celda(a) = New Label
                celda(a).Name = "jugar" & a
                celda(a).Text = ""
                celda(a).Size = New Size(50, 50)
                celda(a).Tag = a
                celda(a).Location = New Point(x, y)
                celda(a).BackColor = Color.Green
                Controls.Add(celda(a))
            Next P2
            y = y + 55
            x = 0
        Next P1
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Randomize()
        Cel = 0 'cel es una variable que ayuda a determinar el lugar de celda a tratar'

        For L1 As Integer = 0 To 2
            For L2 As Integer = 0 To 4
                While True 'Hasta que el número no pertenezca a alguna decena guardada'
                    Rm = Int((Rnd() * 90) + 1) 'Rn significa Número Random'
                    Ten = Int((Rm + 9) / 10) 'Ten significa Centena a la que Rm pertenece'
                    If Not Gen.Contains(Rm) AndAlso Not Dec.Contains(Ten) Then
                        Gen.Add(Rm)
                        Dec.Add(Ten)
                        celda(Val(Cel) + Val(Ten)).Text = Rm.ToString()
                        Exit While
                    End If
                End While
            Next L2
            Cel = Cel + 9
            Dec.Clear()
        Next L1
    End Sub
End Class


De acuerdo al error:

'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

estas tratando de acceder a un método o propiedad de un objeto con valor null, de acuerdo a lo que indicas:

Al cargar el formulario se cargan 27 labels en forma de cartón de
Bingo y cada casilla es un label(a), que va desde el label(0) al label
(26).

Me parece que el problema es que estas definiendo un array con 29 elementos  Dim celda(28) As Label (inicia desde 0) y en el código estaws inicializando desde la celda 1 :
a = 0
...
...
a = a + 1
celda(a)

y hasta la celda 27.
Por lo tanto cambía la inicialización para que solo tenga 27 elementos:
Dim celda(26) As Label


